# Why can't I connect my private Facebook account with Twitter?

Tags: facebook

Why can't I connect my private Facebook account with Twitter? It works with the corporate ones I manage, but not my private account.

Comment: Which application are you using to connect the two together?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Update Twitter with Facebook status](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/10441/update-twitter-with-facebook-status)

Answer (score 1):

You can connect your personal Facebook page to your Twitter account - you just can't do this as easily as corporate pages.  See [this question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/10441/update-twitter-with-facebook-status) for details on how to post to both.

As to "why" this cannot be done - I'm afraid no one here is really going to be able to explain the reasoning for this.  (Not unless a Facebook employee posts the reasons why).

If you really want to know the reasons why, I would suggest that you contact Facebook directly and ask them for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

To link your facebook and twitter accounts click on this link: http://www.teknoplay.blogspot.com/2011/04/how-to-link-your-facebook-and-twitter.html. It will show you how to update your Facebook status via Twitter.