# Update Twitter with Facebook status

Tags: twitter, facebook, status

What is the best way to update Twitter with my Facebook status?

I've tried using the Facebook status RSS feed with Twitterfeed, but Facebook doesn't seem to have RSS feeds for your own status updates anymore. Is there any other way?

Comment: Is updating your Facebook status from the website a requirement?  You could use something like TweetDeck which updates both simultaneously.

Comment: I specifically want a way to push my Facebook status to Twitter, if there is one.

Answer (score 3):

What about: http://apps.facebook.com/twitter/

It looks like ping.fm is the best bet or some 3rd party app. Otherwise you are basically SOL.

Comment: Ping.fm no longer exists.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using [Seesmic Desktop 2](http://seesmic.com/products/desktop)

You add your Twitter & Facebook accounts and then when posting you make sure that both are selected (the green circle)

[image]

**EDIT:**

After a bit more digging - I think you should be able to use http://SocialToo.com You need to register with them and then install the Facebook Application.

Then when posting a Facebook status you use the drop down and select SocialToo Status - this will post then your status update to your Twitter feed as well.
[image]

[Link to SocialToo Facebook Application](http://www.facebook.com/socialtoo?v=info)

Comment: I specifically want a way to push my Facebook status to Twitter, if there is one. I don't want to use a separate a application. I already mentioned this in the comment recommending Tweetdeck.

Comment: @limitedmage - I think the only way for you to do this is to use a 3rd party app like the one I have mentioned.  There doesn't seem to be anything currently available. The FB App that was available no longer works due to changes made to Facebook.

Comment: I'm looking for some sort of app that uses de Facebook and Twitter APIs to do this. I know it's possible because Facebook apps can access current user status and Twitter apps can update your status.

Comment: @limitedmage - I have updated my answer.

Comment: This doesn't work when updating the Facebook status from other apps, eg. Facebook Mobile

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing the exact opposite but I found this... http://www.facebook.com/twitter/

It will probably do the job..

Comment: This only works for pages, I want to update my Twitter status with my personal Facebook profile.

Answer (score 0):

Officially Facebook does not provide RSS feeds for you your status updates anymore. However, there is a way:

1. Note your `FACEBOOK_ID` and `INTERNAL_KEY`. You can find those by going to your notifications page http://www.facebook.com/notifications.php and clicking on "Via RSS" link. The URL structure is as follows:

   `http://www.facebook.com/feeds/notifications.php?id=FACEBOOK_ID&viewer=FACEBOOK_ID&key=INTERNAL_KEY&format=rss20`
2. Use the following URL as your Status Updates RSS feed:

   `http://www.new.facebook.com/feeds/status.php?id=FACEBOOK_ID&viewer=FACEBOOK_ID&key=INTERNAL_KEY&format=rss20`
   (that's the same as using the first link and changing word `notifications` with `status`)
3. Use [twitterfeed](http://twitterfeed.com) to automatically update your Twitter status when your Facebook status is updated. Note that after entering the URL from Step 2 you must also go to advanced settings to only post description of the item.
4. That's it, no go and enjoy it while you can!

Be warned, however, that such a solution might be temporary - Facebook may, for example, decide to change the link. Thus, if you want a robust solution, you might need to move to one of the 3rd party apps or play around with Facebook API yourself.

Comment: When I try this method, I get an error that the feed URL is no longer valid.

Comment: Works perfectly for me, though.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that either general FB privacy, or your own settings are too high, too private, for an unregistered user to access as anything, such as a feed. You'd have to build your own and hardcode in your password to log in for you. I doubt a facebook app could do this, I'm not entirely sure how offline access works.